# STSでのアプリケーションの起動に失敗する

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, oracle

STSがアプリケーションの起動に失敗しているようです。
コンソールにエラーメッセージが表示されます。
もしかしたら、DB周りのメッセージが出ているようなんですが。

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.3.RELEASE)

2020-06-04 11:54:28.474  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] jp.co.sss.shop.ShopApplication           : Starting ShopApplication on DESKTOP-49K9SE0 with PID 8328 (C:\Users\edu\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.0.0.RELEASE\shop\target\classes started by edu in C:\Users\edu\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.0.0.RELEASE\shop)
2020-06-04 11:54:28.477  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] jp.co.sss.shop.ShopApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-06-04 11:54:28.536  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-06-04 11:54:28.536  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-06-04 11:54:29.675  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-06-04 11:54:29.765  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 81ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
2020-06-04 11:54:30.262  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b9dc8257] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-06-04 11:54:30.749  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-06-04 11:54:30.777  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-06-04 11:54:30.777  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.16]
2020-06-04 11:54:30.787  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_111/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_111/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_111/lib/amd64;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;C:\Users\edu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\sts-4.0.0.RELEASE;;.]
2020-06-04 11:54:30.940  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-06-04 11:54:30.941  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2405 ms
2020-06-04 11:54:31.036  WARN 8328 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2020-06-04 11:54:31.042  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-06-04 11:54:31.101  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-06-04 11:54:31.110 ERROR 8328 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Comment: 次の投稿はあなたの質問の回答になりますか？ [Spring bootの起動エラー(DBアクセスに失敗か？)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48348/spring-boot%e3%81%ae%e8%b5%b7%e5%8b%95%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bcdb%e3%82%a2%e3%82%af%e3%82%bb%e3%82%b9%e3%81%ab%e5%a4%b1%e6%95%97%e3%81%8b)

Answer (score 1):

`Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.`
エラーメッセージに原因がかかれているので、その内容通り、設定不足ではないかと思われます。
設定ファイル(application.propertiesなど)に正しいDBアクセスの定義がされているか確認してみてください。

また、[同様の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48348/spring-boot%E3%81%AE%E8%B5%B7%E5%8B%95%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BCdb%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AB%E5%A4%B1%E6%95%97%E3%81%8B)がすでにされているので、こちらも合わせて確認してみてください。